# CPack & productbuild generator: Setting CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE does not work as expected

Tags: macos, cpack

I'm trying to build a Mac OS installer with CMake's CPack for the first time using the `productbuild` generator, which works quite well except for a small detail. In my CMakeLists.txt I set

```
SET (CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Texts/Intro.txt)
SET (CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Texts/Lincese.txt)
```

While the license text is displayed as expected in the installer, the description found in Intro.txt does not appear, instead I see the default text:

[image: Installer screenshot]

What do I have to do in order to make the desired text appear here?

Answer (score 1):

The first page is set with the `CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_WELCOME` variable, the second which you are asking about is set with the `CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_README`, and the third with `CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE`

```
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_WELCOME "Welcome.txt")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_README  "README.txt")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "License.txt")
```

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_README